# Caching Diagnostics recommends 20GB of local storage(!). Why?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-caching

I installed the Azure 1.8 tools/SDK and it upgraded my projects co-located caching from preview to final. However, it also decided to add 20GB to the Role's Local Storage (`DiagnosticStore`). I manually dialed it down to 500MB but then I get the following message in the Role's Property page (cloud proj => roles => right click role => properties i.e. GUI for ServiceDefinition.csdef):

> Caching Diagnostics recommends 20GB of local storage. If you decrease
>   the size of local storage a full redeployment is required which will
>   result in a loss of virtual IP addresses for this Cloud Service.

I don't know who signed off on this operating model within MS but it begs a simple ***Why?***. For better understanding, I'm breaking that "Why" into 3 "Why" subquestions for caching in Azure SDK 1.8:

1. Why is the diagnostics of caching coupled with the caching itself? We just need caching for performance...
2. Why is the recommendation for a whopping 20Gigs? What happens if I dial it down to 500MB?
3. Slightly off-topic but still related: why does the decreasing of local storage require a full redeployment? This is especially painful since Azure doesn't provide any strong controls to reserve IP addresses. So if you need to work with 3rd parties that use whitelisted IPs - too bad!?

PS: I did contemplate breaking it into 3 separate questions. But given that they are tightly coupled it seems this would be a more helpful approach for future readers.

Comment: The only reason I can think it requires a full redeployment is because it has to create a new VHD with the correct size for the local storage on that instance. As to why so much? Who knows what size you need for diagnostics etc, hopefully someone would shed some light.

Answer (score 2):

Diagnostic store is used for storing cache diagnostic data which includes - server logs, crash dumps, counter data etc. which can be automatically uploaded to Azure Storage by configuring the cache diagnostics (CacheDiagnostics.ConfigureDiagnostics call in OnStart method - without this call, data is generated on local VM but not uplaoded into Azure Storage ). And the amount of data that is collected is controlled by diagnostic level (higher the level, more data is collected) which can be changed dynamically. More details on cache diagnostics is avialble at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914135.aspx

1. Since you enabled cache, it will come with default diagnostic level that should help in diagnosing cache issues if they happen. This data is stored locally unless you call the ConfigureDiagnostics method in OnStart (which uploads the data to Azure storage).
2. If a lower storage value is provided (say 2GB), then higher diagnostic levels cannot be used since they need more space (crash dump itself can take upwards 12GB for XL VMs). And if you want higher levels, then you might want to upgrade the deployment with change in the diagnostic store size which defeats the purpose - change diagnostic level without redeployment/upgrade/update/restarts. That is the reason why a limit of 20GB is set to cater to all diagnostic levels (and they can be changed in a running deployment with cscfg change).
3. is answered above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer question #3 - local storage *decreases* are one of the only deployment changes that can't be done in-place (increases are fine, as well as VM size changes and several other changes now possible without redeploy). See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates.aspx) for details around in-place updates.

Comment: But you can still VIP swap, which doesn't result in a changing IP address. Right?